# Why did Rav Chiya bar Ashi recite Birchat haTorah before learning?

Tags: blessing, birchos-hatorah

[Here, on Brachot 11b,](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.11b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) , the Gemara says that Rav Chiya bar Ashi said Birchat HaTorah prior to learning Sifrei, in an effort to demonstrate that one should recite the blessings before learning Talmud. My question, however, is: why did Rav Chiya bar Ashi need to recite this if he presumably already said them during Birchot HaShachar (and the accepted halacha is that we say it once in the morning)? My two possible ideas: either this was before davening, which seems unlikely, or maybe Rav Chiya bar Ashi said the bracha every time he learned. Perhaps someone has some insight on this.

Comment: Birkhot haTorah are specifically only for people who wake up early to learn before davening. It says so right there a few lines before this story.

Comment: Rashi used to make birchas ha'torah when he got up early to learn and then he would say birchas ha'torah again during birchot ha'shachar. He said you see it is possible to make birchas ha'torah many times for you make birchas ha'torah in the birchat ha'shachar and then you say birchat ha'torah again if you get an aliyah. Tosafos is of the opinion you can only make birchas ha'torah once, and seems to hold that the berachah you make when you get an aliyah is on the public Torah reading, as opposed to the berachah you make in birchat ha'shachar which is for your personal study.

Comment: Tosfos says to make one birkat Hatorah